# How to remove auto height of grid rows in TailwindCSS using Laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS to create a grid and show my content.

This grid section is in a loop through my product attributes.

Here is how I am doing this :

```
<div class="p-4 grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        <div>
            <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
                <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
                    Header
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
            Table content
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

As you can see in this example I have a two cols every row and in this loop in every row will be create two tables for me.

But my product attributes does not have same content and because of that the height of every table (every col in every row) will be different.

Because of this different, when in first row I have two cols with different height the second row will be start from end of the higher col from previous row.

But I don't want this default space and I want to every rows and every cols start exactly after previous parent.

Here is an image you can see the problem :

[image]

For example in this image I want to *Axial Fan* section start after *Coil* with no space.

***There is no need to use grid template, any idea to do this problem is good.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide `$attributes` into two separate groups, and then render each group in their own wrapper within the grid:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-200">
  <div class="p-4 grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
    <div class="space-y-6">
      <div>
        <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
          <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
            Header
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
          <div class="h-96">Table content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
 
      <div>
        <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
          <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
            Header
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
          <div class="h-40">Table content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space-y-6">
      <div>
        <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
          <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
            Header
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
          <div class="h-36">Table content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
 
      <div>
        <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
          <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
            Header
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
          <div class="h-80">Table content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As a blade template:

```html
<div class="p-4 grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
  @foreach ([$oddAttributes, $evenAttributes] as $attributes)
    <div class="space-y-6">
      @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        <div>
          <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
              <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
                  Header
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-white">
            Table content
          </div>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could look at using [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) to have the elements distributed (somewhat) evenly like newspaper columns. You'd probably want to apply [`break-inside: avoid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside#avoid) to avoid breaks with tables/headings:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-200">
  <div class="p-4 columns-2 gap-6 space-y-6">
    <div class="break-inside-avoid">
      <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
        <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
          Header
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="h-96">Table content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="break-inside-avoid">
      <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
        <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
          Header
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="h-40">Table content</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="break-inside-avoid">
      <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
        <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
          Header
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="h-36">Table content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="break-inside-avoid">
      <div class="bg-green-800 p-2">
        <p class="text-lg font-bold text-center text-white">
          Header
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="h-80">Table content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Assume I divide attributes by even and odd indexes into $oddAttributes and $evenAttributes, Can you update your answer and put foreach using this comment ?

Comment: I added a blade template example into the answer instead of in these comments for better readability.